# Check if string array index is equal to string

Tags: java

So I'm trying to check a list of account names to see if the username entered by the operator is in the database or not. At the moment I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++){
            System.out.println("Stored in array:" + accounts[i+1]);
            System.out.println("name entered:" + LoginPage.usrname);
            if(accounts[i+1] == LoginPage.usrname){
                System.out.println("match");
            }else{
                System.out.println("no match");
            }
        }
```

I tried messing around with things like indexOf string and can't get anything to work. I'm sure there's a simple solution, just having trouble finding one. I don't understand why I can't compare a String array index to a String variable, seems like ti should be cake.

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string contents, not the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
if(acounts[i+1].equals(LoginPage.usrname))
```

Using the `==` operator on `Strings` in `Java` doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't compare the contents of the `Strings`, but rather their addresses in memory.  The `equals` method compares the contents of the `Strings`.

---

As a note that may help you remember, this isn't anything particularly special about `Strings`.  `Strings` are objects, and in `Java`, using `==` to compare objects of ANY type will present the same problem.  If you want to compare the contents of two objects of a custom class you create, you'll have to write an `equals` method for that class.  `Strings` work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

String are unique reference type that behave like value type.

At Java when trying to compare String's using `==` operator, Java will try to check if both of the reference are equals, **Not the strings**.
In order to achieve a value type comparison you will be to use one of the following:

Method 1: `str1.equals(str)`
Method 2: `str1.compareTo(str) == 0`